# RowID in Teradata

Tags: java, sql, database, teradata

I need to pull a row ID with a select statement. Something that is similar to the row ID of oracle. How would I do that in Teradata? I am trying the following query but it is throwing error.

```
select rowid,emp_id,e_name from test;

Error msg : Syntax error: ROWID not allowed.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found something that might solve your problem http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/rowid-in-teradata but I am not sure if it will work in your case

Comment: Hi AurA, I tried the same query which is mentioned in the link provided by you. But it is throwing an error like 'ROWID not allowed'.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `ROW_NUMBER()` window aggregate function:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY empid) AS RowID_
     , empid
     , empName
  FROM test;
```

Unlike `RANK()` the `ROW_NUMBER()` window aggregate will not permit ties to occur in the result set. Your other alternative would be to use an `IDENTITY` column in your table but those are messy and cause problems down the road. It is easier to incorporate `ROW_NUMBER()` in your ETL processing if you need to maintain a surrogate key.

It should be noted that if your `ORDER BY` or `PARTITION BY` column is skewed, your performance on the `STAT FUNCTION` step in the query plan me be impacted for large sets of data. The `PARTITION BY` clause is optional and allows you to define a window where the result of the `ROW_NUMBER()` would be reset when the partition changes. Not commonly used with `ROW_NUMBER()` but it may come in handy.

**Edit**
To uniquely identify the record with a surrogate and not have to rely on logic in your ETL use and identity column in your table. Configured correctly the IDENTITY column will not reuse any domain values when records are deleted.

Comment: Also note that this is not the same thing as an Oracle "rowid". In Oracle, a "rowid" is the permanent address of a particular row in a table (at least that's how I think it works).  Using `ROW_NUMBER` will give different results if new rows have been inserted into the table.  I don't think there is a similar concept in Teradata. Just a caution and +1.

Comment: I need unique id to identify each row and this id should not get change even if we delete some records.

Comment: See latest edit on using an IDENTITY column in your table for a surrogate.